# Prometheus + Grafana on multiple nodes using docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, grafana, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I am setting up prometheus + grafana with cadvisor and node_exporter. I need to gather metrics for 2+ servers. But lets say I am gonna do it for 2 not. I am using docker compose.

On Master server I have this configs:

```
[root@172.31.115.207 ~]# cat prometheus.yml 
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: prometheus
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
    - targets:
      - prometheus:9090
      - pushgateway:9091
  - job_name: docker
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
    - targets:
      - 172.31.115.207:9323
  - job_name: cadvisor
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
    - targets: ['172.31.112.84:8080','172.31.115.207:8080']
  - job_name: node-exporter
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
    - targets: ['172.31.112.84:9100','172.31.115.207:9100']

cat prometheus.yml
      - 172.31.115.207:9323
  - job_name: cadvisor
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
    - targets: ['172.31.112.84:8080','172.31.115.207:8080']
  - job_name: node-exporter
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
    - targets: ['172.31.112.84:9100','172.31.115.207:9100'] 
[root@pivanko1c ~]# cat docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    container_name: prometheus
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    command:
      - --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml:ro
    depends_on:
      - cadvisor
  cadvisor:
    image: google/cadvisor:latest
    container_name: cadvisor
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - /:/rootfs:ro
      - /var/run:/var/run:rw
      - /sys:/sys:ro
      - /var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro
  pushgateway:
    image: prom/pushgateway
    container_name: pushgateway
    ports:
      - 9091:9091
  node-exporter:
    image: prom/node-exporter:latest
    container_name: node-exporter
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 9100:9100
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    container_name: grafana
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD=Uniform189
    depends_on:
      - prometheus
      - cadvisor
```

And here is my docker-compose.yml; on worker server

```
[root@172.31.112.84 ~]# cat docker-compose.yml 
version: '3'
services:
  cadvisor:
    image: google/cadvisor:latest
    container_name: cadvisor
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - /:/rootfs:ro
      - /var/run:/var/run:rw
      - /sys:/sys:ro
      - /var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro
  node-exporter:
    image: prom/node-exporter:latest
    container_name: node-exporter
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 9100:9100
```

When I have setup only master everything looks nice in grafana. But when I start containers on worker node everything goes wrong in grafana. I only see number of containers. Everything else is N/A.

Please could you advise where is the problem in my configs? I want to have nice view in grafana where I can select node1 or node2 and see all the metrics.

Thank you

Comment: Can you show your grafana dashboard and what's wrong with it. Did you create it or is it imported? It's possible that your prom and docker-compose configs are correct but your dashboard might not be set up properly?

Comment: hello, thank you for your comment. I donwloaded dashboard from here: 

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/linuxacademy/content-intermediate-docker-quest-prometheus/master/dashboards/docker_and_system.json 

It is possible that the issue is with dashboard because I this dashboard I get from training which I wateched - but training considered only 1 node.

Otherwise have you checked the configs above? Does it look more or less ok? At least the concept which I am using?

Comment: `static_configs: - targets: ['host.docker.internal:8080']` https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/prometheus/ worked for me to connect two services in different docker-compose files.